# How to install Android studio in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04, android-sdk-tools

I have already downloaded the android studio IDE.zip and also downloaded the android SDK.

How do I install it,  I'm new to Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu you can use 2 approvach to install `Android Studio` First one is use the new Developer tools that Ubuntu Team integrated directly on ubuntu. For that you can follow this manual (is writted by an Ubuntu Team member)

https://paolorotolo.github.io/android-studio/

If you want to use the latest version you can simple unzip the file you already have and run the /bin/studio.sh file.
To do that, first check if the file `studio.sh` has run permissions pressing right click in the file, properties --> permission tab.

After that, open a terminal `cntrl + alt + t` and navigate to the folder where you unzip Android Studio. 
Then after make `cd /bin` run studio.sh with `./studio.sh &`

When you have Studio running you can go to `Configure` option and then select `Create Desktop Entry` to create a entry in your Unity launcher

Comment: when i run /studio.sh it says no such file :\ ? what can i do right now

Answer (score 1):

You can install Android studio in Ubuntu with apt or apt-get command.
Please use the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```